# Debian 7: connection problems and timeouts

Tags: linux, connection, debian

On my root server, debian 7 is the operation system. Running kernel is 2.6.32.
I have the problem, that TCP/IP-connections seems to be "unstable".
ssh connections often hang or timeout. Webserver sometimes runs fast, sometimes the client (browser) is waiting and waiting for a response.
I dont know where to start right now for this problems. I made a hardware check requests at my ISP ticket system.
Is there a hint you can give me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a broken network adapter in the mainframe of the cluster. The provided fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is DNS related. I would isolate one destination to communicate to, and one location to communicate from. Using ping, I would determine if there was latency in the link itself (ping from the server to one destination and from your client workstation to the troubled server). Once you determine that times are predictable (no **'s)I would learn both IP addresses and put them in /etc/hosts.

When you run ssh I would consider using -vv to see what it is doing and maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will check hosts and hostname for sure. Its a general connection problem, ping and many tracerts seem to be well. I can easily see the problem when using ssh. Using putty from windows, but will try -vv from linux box. I deactivated UseDNS, X11-Forward, and so on, but i guess the problem is also a bit deeper

Comment: the kernel was the problem together with the current glib. after some updates, it disappeared. thanks